# generates:s:Supporting C++14 digit separators in listings package

Tags: listings

Since C++14 you can write literals like this:

```
1'000'000
0b1111'1111
```

That is you can use single quotes between digits to make them more readable.

However the usual C/C++ listings styles start to interpret the single quote as beginning of a char/string (which ends with the next digit separator if any or never if none).

For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{%
  language=C++,
  stringstyle=\color{red},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
main()
{
  int i = 1'000'000;
  int j = 0b111'111; 
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

generates:

[image]

How can I fix that?

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide a minimum working example that demonstrates the issue?  It will save time for those who might otherwise try to help you.

Comment: done (dont know how to show the effect/output though)

Comment: Once you get enough reputation, you can add images into your questions.  In the meantime, I have edited your question to add the result.

Comment: Ugly workaround using `escapeinside`: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{%
  language=C++,
  stringstyle=\color{red},
  escapeinside={(*@}{@*)},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
main()
{
  int i = 1(*@'@*)000(*@'@*)000;
  int j = 0b111(*@'@*)111; 
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}`

Comment: yes, or disabling the special handling of `'` as a string with  `deletestring=[b]'`,  but of course I wanted to have a general solution (in fact, we should have a way to have a working notation for standard C++)

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the `'` as a string delimiter (which is even wrong in C++) but at the same time you lose highlighting for character literals.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{upquote}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{%
  language=C++,
  stringstyle=\color{red},
  deletestring=[b]{'}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
main()
{
  int i = 1'000'000;
  int j = 0b111'111;
  char c = 'a';
  std::string s = "Hello world!\n";
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]